# Solving $a_2(t)\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+a_1(t)\frac{du}{dt}+a_0(t)u=f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

> Let  $$Lu=f$$ be
>   $$a_2(t)\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+a_1(t)\frac{du}{dt}+a_0(t)u=f$$ Let $u_0$ be
>   a solution for $Lu=0$.  Assume that the solution $u$ is of the form
>   $u=u_0v$
>
> a) from the equation $Lu=f$ derive a second order equation for $v$.

My attempt:

$$a_2(t)\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+a_1(t)\frac{du}{dt}+a_0(t)u=f$$
Now let $u=u_0v$, if we substitute this in the equation we get
$$a_2(t)\frac{d^2u_0v}{dt^2}+a_1(t)\frac{du_0v}{dt}+a_0(t)u_0v=f$$
$$a_2(t)[u_0(t)v(t)''+2u_0'(t)v'(t)+u''_0(y)v(t)]+a_1(t)[u_0(t)v'(t)+u'_0(t)v(t)]+a_0(t)u_0(t)v(t)=f$$
$$\frac{d^2v}{dt^2}a_2(t)u_0+\frac{dv}{dt}(2a_2(t)u'_0+a_1(t)u_0)(a_2(t)u''_0+a_1(t)u'_0+a_0(t)u_0) =f$$
$$\frac{d^2v}{dt^2}a_2(t)u_0+\frac{dv}{dt}(2a_2(t)u'_0+a_1(t)u_0)=f$$

So far I think I'm right, but here is where i got stuck

> b) let w= v'and solve the differential equation for $w$

My attempt:
\If we take $w=\frac{dv}{dt}$, we get
$$\frac{dw}{dt}a_2(t)u_0+w(2a_2(t)u'_0+a_1(t)u_0)=f$$
First solve homogenous equation 
$$\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{(-2a_2(t)u'_0-a_1(t)u_0)w(t)}{a_2(t)u_0}$$

$$\frac{dw}{dt} \frac{a_2(t)u_0}{w(t)}=2a_2(t)u'_0-a_1(t)u_0$$
View everything except the $w(t)$ as a constant and integrate to $t$
$$\int_{t_0}^t \frac{dw}{dt} \frac{a_2(t)u_0}{w(t)} dt=\int_{t_0}^t  2a_2(t)u'_0-a_1(t)u_0 dt$$
$$a_2(t)u(t)log(w(t))-a_2(t_0)u(t_0)log(w(t_0))=\int_{t_0}^t  2a_2(t)u'_0-a_1(t)u_0dt $$
$$log(w(t))=\frac{\int_{t_0}^t  2a_2(t)u'_0-a_1(t)u_0 dt +a_2(t_0)u(t_0)log(w(t_0))}{a_2(t)u(t)}$$
$$w(t)= \exp\Big[\frac{\int_{t_0}^t  2a_2(t)u'_0-a_1(t)u_0 dt}{a_2(t)u(t)}\Big]\cdot w(t_0)^{\frac{a_2(t_0)u(t_0)}{a_2(t)u(t)}}$$

Which is a horrible equation and its not even with the inhomogenous part

**This is a homework question, so I'd like a hint or to be told where I went wrong, nog a full answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to check whether your derivation up to the equation in $w(t)$ is correct.

The equation isn't horrible. It just looks that way when you have so many variables.

Since $a_1(t)$, $a_2(t)$ and $u_0(t)$ are all known functions, let

\begin{align}
p(t) &= \frac{2a_2(t)u_0'(t) + a_1(t)u_0(t)}{a_2(t)u_0(t)} \\
q(t) &= \frac{f(t)}{a_2(t)u_0(t)}
\end{align}

Then the first order equation reduces to

$$ \frac{dw}{dt} + p(t)w = q(t) $$

You can solve this using the standard integrating factor method, which results in

$$ w(t) = e^{-\int p(t) dt}\int \left[ e^{\int p(t) dt}q(t)\right] dt $$